# retrieve and extract links (Linux/Windows)

Tags: linux, extract, links

I have a "source.txt" file which contains list of some URLs. For example:

```
source.txt:    
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007OZNZG0/ref=s9_pop_gw_g349_ir05/176-5131847-6150405?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=02R1PYSDAPM8P0XF7HXW&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1263340922&pf_rd_i=507846
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0083PWAPW/ref=s9_pop_gw_g424_ir04/176-5131847-6150405?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=02R1PYSDAPM8P0XF7HXW&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1263340922&pf_rd_i=507846
```

I want to **retrieve** each link inside "source.txt" and **search through the html of each** and extract all links from them which contain **"/gp/product"** and then store them in "extracted.txt" file, which would be similar to:

```
extracted.txt:
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008GFRB9E/ref=fs_j
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008GFUA4C/ref=fs_2
...
```

I am using Windows 7 (64 bit) and Cygwin, so I can run Linux commands as well.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question.  The first time I read it, I thought a simple `grep` (as in ssmy’s answer) was what you wanted.  Now I’ve read your question 2½ times, and I guess you mean that you want to _retrieve_ each of the web pages whose URLs you have, and then _search through the HTML_ for “`/gp/product`”.  Is that what you mean?  If so, I believe you should look at `wget`.

Comment: I modified the question. Yes, I mean retrieve and search through the URLs in "source.txt".

Comment: You can use "wget -qO- -i source.txt | grep /gp/product" but that will output the lines containing "/gp/product" with all html-tags etc.

Comment: @FSMaxB Thank you. I tried and you are right. The output is the lines with "href="/gp/product/", while it should be "http://www.amazon.com/gp/product". Any suggestions how to modify this?

Comment: @Si14 Maybe you can use awk or sed to extract the actual links from this list, but I don't know how to do it. At least it's a first step.

Answer (score -1):

In a bash shell you can use grep. `grep "/gp/product/" source.txt >extracted.txt`

Comment: The above command searches for that keyword only in the source.txt and does not open and search the URLs in it. I tried it in Cygwin. I am not sure how to test it on bash shell? Do you have suggestions?